# Configuration a Play dependency injection module as a trait

Tags: dependency-injection, playframework

In the [Play module scaladocs](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/inject/Module.scala#L31-L33) :

> It is strongly advised that in addition to providing a module for JSR-330 DI, that plugins also provide a Scala trait that constructs the modules manually.  This allows for use of the module without needing a runtime dependency injection provider.

If the construction of my module depends on `play.api.Configuration` can I just use the `ConfigFactory.load("application")` to create that dependency, and then just create a factory for my module like so:

```
object MyModule {
  def apply(config: Config) = {
    val credentials = /* construct from config */
    new MyModule(credentials)
  }
}
```

I guess I'm wondering, how should I construct the module in a trait if the module requires itself a dependency injectable resource? What if my trait needed something else, like `environment`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define abstract members in your trait. That means the code requiring your module will have to provide those. For instance with your example

```scala
// your definition
trait MyModuleComponents {
  def configuration: Configuration

  lazy val module = new MyModule(configuration)
}

// usage
class MyApp extends MyModuleComponents {
  // provide configuration here
  val configuration = ConfigFactory.load("application")

  // use module
  module.doSomething()
}
```

For a better example, you can look at [how play does it for WsClient](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-ahc-ws/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/ws/ahc/AhcWSComponents.scala#L17) for instance